# Validations and passing ModelState from Service Layer to Controller WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

I was following the below link to get the validations done at Service Layer
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

I ended up having cyclic dependency. So remove dependency injection of validation/ModelStateWrapper and used Initialize static way.

Brief Explanation about the Project: I have API, Services Layer, Repository, Database. I am using Automapper to map DTO's to Entities.
Controller:

```
public StudentController(IStudentService studentService, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _studentService = studentService;
            _studentService.Initialize(new ModelStateWrapper(this.ModelState));
            _mapper = mapper;
        } 

    public IActionResult CreateStudent([FromBody] StudentCreationDto student)
            {    
                if (student== null)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }                         
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(ModelState);
                }
                var studentEnitty = _mapper.Map<Student>(student);
                var createSuccessful = _studentService.CreateStudent(studentEnitty);
                if (!createSuccessful)
                {                
                    return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(ModelState);
                }  
            }
```

Service:

```
public void Initialize(IValidationDictionary validationDictionary)
                {
                    _validationDictionary = validationDictionary;
                }

public bool CreateStudent(Student student)
            {
                //Check if Student already exists
                if (!ValidateStudentToCreate(student))
                {                
                    return false;
                }

                //Create Portal 
                var createSuccessful = _studentRepository.CreateStudent(student);
                if (!createSuccessful)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

    private bool ValidateStudentToCreate(Student student)
    {
        //throw new Exception();            
        if (_studentRepository.StudentEmailExists(student.Email))
        {
            _validationDictionary.AddError("Email", "Student already exists");
        }             

        bool isValid = _validationDictionary.IsValid;
        return isValid;
    }
```

I have IValidation dictionary with AddError and IsValid. ModelStateWrapper Implements IValidationDictionary.

IValidation Dictionary

```
public interface IValidationDictionary
    {
        void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
        bool IsValid { get; }
    }
```

ModelStateWrapper

```
public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidationDictionary
    {       

        private ModelStateDictionary _modelState;

        public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            _modelState = modelState;
        }

        #region IValidationDictionary Members


        public void AddError(string key, string errorMessage)
        {
            _modelState.AddModelError(key, errorMessage);
        }          

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return _modelState.IsValid; }
        }
```

I am trying to get the data model validations at Controller level and Business logic such as Student exists at Service level. I am able to execute the validations however, i am unable to get the model state back to Controller as it says valid. Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Which line of code above are you encountering the problem?

Comment: Hello Jasen, Let us say when the validation is done, and the student email already exists. Then i want to be able to pass the ModelState back to controller. 

Controller has an instance of service injected into it's constructor. The constructor calls the service.initialize and passed Validation Dictionary which in turn contains Model State Object. So, if there s a validation error , the CreateStudent method should return false. Also, the controller should return the Model State, this is where i am having problem. I see the ModelState is still valid on the controller.

Comment: You mean that you want to validate `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` on controller?You need to know `ModelState.IsValid` indicates if it was possible to bind the incoming values from the request to the model correctly and whether any explicitly specified validation rules were broken during the model binding process.You did not custom  validation for ModelState and request with the right format,so ModelState would is valid on the controller.

Comment: Rena, I understand the custom validation. I want to get the validations from business logic or service later such as if entity exists. It is not regarding ViewModel/DTO validation. If you check the Controller that part of it done initially.

Comment: Jasen, The model state in the below code is not getting the info from the Service layer. Can you help ? if (!createSuccessful)
                {                
                    return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(ModelState);
                }

Comment: Show us your code for the `IValidationDictionary` and `ModelStateWrapper` implementations.

Comment: Jasen, please see the post. I have edited and added IValidationDictionary and ModelStateWrapper Implementations.I really appreciate you taking time to answer this question.

Comment: Jasen, were you able to find anything?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here. I haven't had the chance to try this in an asp.net core project.

Comment: Thank you Jasen. Let me know when ever you get a chance to try it out.